# How to use ngrok with puma-dev rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ngrok, puma-dev

My rails app is spin up using puma-dev on Ubuntu.

I'm using `puma-dev` command to start my app (in foreground) and then access the rails app using
`https://app.test:9283`.
As the puma-dev is running in the foreground I have to use the port 9283 to access the port.

Now I want to access the rails app on remote machines like a mobile device or other PC. So have to use the `ngrok` to do so. I have installed `ngrok` in my ubuntu but I'm not able to access my localhost setup running on `https://app.test:9283` using ngrok. Any help would be appreciated!

NOTE: When I use `./ngrok http 80` it successfully redirects me to `localhost:80` which means ngrok is working properly.

Comment: I haven't use ngrok in a couple of years, but I remember running "rails s -b 0.0.0.0" and then "ngrok http 3000", by my understand ngrok will tunnel your open port to a temp address on the port 80, so you should be going to app.test instead of app.test:3000 and the addresses were like #####.ngrok.io, you could change the port with something like "rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3001"

Comment: What command are you running to start `ngrok`? It could be something like `ngrok http 9283`.

Comment: running `ngrok http 9283` gives me `Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.`

Answer (score 4):

With `puma-dev` it is necessary to include the `-host-header` argument, like so:

```
./ngrok http -host-header=app.test 9283
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to bind the ngrok server with the same port as rails server **./ngrok http 9283**

Comment: running `./ngrok http 9283` gives me Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.

Answer (score 0):

You need ["local-leg HTTPS."](https://ngrok.com/docs#http-local-https)

`./ngrok http https://app.test:9283`

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to connect to my locally running app securely was by running the next command:

```bash
ngrok http https://app.localhost --host-header app.localhost
```

without any ports and the `https://` address before the `--host-header`